# Amazon S3 - Carrierwave Image Upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

So, I'm trying to upload an image from the Rails API to S3, using Fog.

Whenever I try to upload the image, I get this:

```
  Excon::Errors::Forbidden (Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden)
  (...)
  All access to this object has been disabled
```

It is working in development, but once I switch to production, I receive the error above. I'm using the keys from an user I've created that set full administrative permissions to.

My carrierwave.rb: 
require 'carrierwave'

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|

  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => "AWS",
    :region                 => "us-east-1",
    :aws_access_key_id      => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :aws_secret_access_key  => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }

  if Rails.env.production?  
    config.cache_dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
  end

  config.fog_directory  = ENV['AWS_BUCKET']
  config.fog_public     = false
end
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Required full backtrace for investigate problem.

Comment: You should check if ENV have all your parameters that you need in prodaction. From where you get ENV ?

Comment: @denys28, Dumb mistake. Forgot to add the region ENV on Heroku. Everything working ok now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the problem was related to the ENV on Heroku.
I forgot to add the REGION variable.

So, it's worth checking if you have all your variables set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Always make sure you have the right ENV variables and the the correct S3 keys.

This was the problem in my case.